# SVN hook and Windows batch script, whats wrong?

Tags: svn, batch-file, post-commit-hook

I want to use svnlook to only update those files of a repository that were changed/added and so on automatically. I have several apps in my repository and all could have changed files. Running *svnlook changed pathtomyrep* gives me the files, thats step one. How do I use that in a batch file to update only the changed files in a commit hook? I have this batch file (post-commit.bat):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
SET CHANGES=svnlook changed %REPOS% -r %REV% 
FOR /F "usebackq" %%a IN (`%CHANGES%`) DO (svn update %%a)
```

Bute nothing happens, the code is not updated! I know the file works in general, when I enter other stuff, its executed. Testing it locally, instead of *U filename* I only get *U*. Whats wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: `for /?` says "By default, /F passes the first blank separated token from each line of each file.". You can tell `/F` to use the second token if you can guarantee it will always be second - I can't remember svnlook output but you can't guarantee that for svn update output. Can you get svnlook to return only the filenames and not the status character?

Comment: Lets see, at least *usebackq tokens=2* returns me the name only. When I run it the new way, svn update says its skipping the file ... strange. Can you see anything else that might be wrong?

Comment: I figured it out! I neeed the full path! So I added *SET MYPATH=d:\apache\htdocs* and added this in front of the svn update!

Comment: 'Skipped XYZ' means that 1) we're not in a working copy 2) there's no working copy at path XYZ. Are you defnitely updating the correct place? Do you need to `pushd c:\the_working_copy` first and then `popd` at the end?

Comment: See above! You put me on the right track, thanks! **Solved**

Answer (score 1):

> **I want to** *(use svnlook to)* **only update those files of a repository that were changed/added and so on automatically.**

You're not too clear what you want to do.

1. Are you running some sort of ...say... website, and when a developer changes a file in your Subversion repository, you want to automatically update your website with those changes?
2. Are you watching a directory, and when files change in that directory, you want to save those changes into your Subversion repository?

---

I'm assuming you want to do #1 because #2 is impossible to do with a post-commit or pre-commit hook script. A pre-commit/post-commit hook script only runs when someone does a commit, so it can't change the directory itself.

So, you have files in your repository and a directory on some sort of server that uses those files. You want a process to automatically update those files when there's a change in the repository.

A few ways to handle this:

1. On the machine that contains the server and the files. Make sure that directory that contains the files is a Subversion working directory. If you use a Subversion 1.7, the only `.svn` directory is in the root of the working directory which makes things a bit cleaner and easier to manage. Now, all you need is a scheduled task (a cronjob in Unix parlance) that fires off ...say... every five minutes. All this task does is run an update on that working directory. No post-commit hook is needed.
2. You could have a working directory on your Subversion server that's accessible to the post-commit hook script. When a commit happens, the post-commit hook updates that working directory, then does a [rsync](http://rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html) to the directory on the server where you have these files. The *rsync* will only copy over files that have been changed and thus is faster than copying over the entire directory contents. The problem is that after every commit, the user who did the commit has to wait for the post-commit hook to update that working directory and the rsync before they can do anything else.
3. A better way is to use a continuous integration tool like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to automatically do whatever you need to do whenever someone does a commit instead of relying upon a post-commit hook. Jenkins will log everything and let you know if there were problems.

My preference would be #3 and then #1. Using a post-commit hook simply slows Subversion down and frustrates your developers. Jenkins is easy to setup and get running. Their support is excellent, and like Subversion, it's a free open source tool.

You could setup Jenkins to automatically have the server that contains these files to automatically run an update after a commit. In fact, that's extremely easy to setup. I normally recommend the following though:

1. Your server is configured to use directory `C:\foo`.
2. Update a commit, you create a directory `C:\bar` and do a `svn export` to create a new and clean directory without any `.svn` directories.
3. After the `svn export finishes, you rename`C:\bar`to`C:\foo`. Your server now is using the new directory.

This has the advantage that your server isn't using a directory while the files are in the process of being updated. Imagine there are three files, `filea.txt`, `fileb.txt`, and `filec.txt`. A change is made to `fileb.txt` and `filec.txt`. These changes go together and disastrous consequences will happen if they aren't deployed at the same time (you get fired).

At some point in the update process, `fileb.txt` will be at the new version while `filec.txt` will be at the older version. Sure, it's highly unlikely that your server will use both the new version of `fileb.txt` and the older version of `filec.txt` before the update completes, but ***would you want to bet your job on that?***.

So, take a look at Jenkins which will do what you want without slowing down Subversion. Plus, it will log all of its actions. This way, you can see what files were changed, whether the update was successful, and the ability to easily roll back changes if required. Plus, it's a lot easier to temporarily stop Jenkins from doing the update on those occasions when you might not want particular changes going to your server process.